# My cryptanalyis of an affine cipher isn't working 100% of the time

Tags: python, modular-arithmetic, cryptanalysis

I have to create a function that takes input as letters from a frequency analysis of the English language, "p1" and "p2", as well as a frequency analysis of the cipher-text, "C1" and "C2", as well as the alphabet length I am using "AL". I have created a function in Python to do this but it only works some of the time. Other times it gives me an error and I don't know why.
The 2 equations are:
s(r+p1)=C1(mod AL)
s(r+p2)=C2(mod AL)

The code is supposed to calculate the multiplicative and additive keys for decrypting the given cipher-text.

Here is my code - the first function calculates the multiplicative modular inverse and the second function implements the equations.

```
def ModInverse(a, m):
    if gcd(a, m) != 1:
        return 'These are not co-prime.'

    # Calculate using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm:
    u1, u2, u3 = 1, 0, a
    v1, v2, v3 = 0, 1, m
    while v3 != 0:
        q = u3 // v3
        v1, v2, v3, u1, u2, u3 = (u1 - q * v1), (u2 - q * v2), (u3 - q * v3), v1, v2, v3
    return u1 % m
```

```
def decryption_keys_affine(p1, p2, C1, C2, AL):

    s = p2 - p1

    p3 = s * p1

    p4 = (p3 % AL)

    p5 = C1 - p4

    p6 = AL + p5

    p7 = ModInverse(s, AL)

    p8 = p7 * p6

    r = p8 % AL

    multi = ModInverse(s, AL)
    add = AL - r

    print(multi, add)
```

When I give it this input:

```
>>> decryption_keys_affine(5, 20, 9, 26, 26)
7 20
>>>
```

It displays the proper answers.

When I give it this input:

```
>>> decryption_keys_affine(5, 20, 41, 18, 42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    decryption_keys_affine(5, 20, 41, 18, 42)
  File "C:\Users\Herman\Desktop\crypto_math_functions.py", line 108, in decryption_keys_affine
    r = p8 % AL
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

It gives me that error and I don't know why. (The alphabet length for the first is 26 and for the second includes 10 digits and 6 symbols making it 42).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this line:

```
return 'These are not co-prime.'
```

The `%` operator performs the modulo operation *when applied to integers*.

When applied to *strings*, it instead performs string formatting. In the case where the arguments provided to `ModInverse` are not coprime, it returns a string, which `r = p8 % AL` tries to format. Since the return string contains no format specifiers, it raises an exception.

Rather than returning a string in such a situation, you should raise your own exception, for example:

```
def ModInverse(a, m):
    if gcd(a, m) != 1:
        raise ValueError('The input arguments, {} and {}, are not coprime.'.format(a, m))

    # Calculate using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm:
    u1, u2, u3 = 1, 0, a
    v1, v2, v3 = 0, 1, m
    while v3 != 0:
        q = u3 // v3
        v1, v2, v3, u1, u2, u3 = (u1 - q * v1), (u2 - q * v2), (u3 - q * v3), v1, v2, v3
    return u1 % m
```

Comment: I made that change, are my equations in python for calculating the multiplicative and additive keys to decipher the affine correct?

Comment: I...think so? I wouldn't be certain.